# Unable to get an IP for my Raspberry in WIndows 8

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have connected my Raspberry 2 to my PC with an ethernet cable and a USB cable. I use wifi. But when I try to enable sharing I see these options in the drop-down.

```
Ethernet
Virtualbox host-only network
VMWare network adapter vmnet 1
VMWare network adapter vmnet 8
Npcap loopback adapter
```

Which one should I use ?

If I choose 'Ethernet' and execute nmap I don't see the raspberry host name or IP in the result.

So I couldn't get an IP for my Raspberry.

Mine is a fresh pi. I hope I can use it like this. It should have NOOBS. Right ?

Comment: Bridge the connection between the ethernet and Wifi adapter. I remember doing this with my Xbox when I was a child, it should be the same procedure; https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/networking/win-computer

Comment: I believe you mean the section 'Set up a network bridge connection'..WIll try but didn't see that in the general raspberry references anywhere.

Comment: the ethernet protocol is standard, if itll work on xbox, it should work on the Pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I observed when I connected a monitor to the Pi.

The very first time the new Pi boots it didn't have access to the internet. The NOOBS boot screen showed a dialog message that it couldn't access the distribution list.

So I disconnected the ethernet cable from the PC and connected it to the router.

And it had access to the distribution list and the GUI showed other operating systems that I can choose. But NOOBS continued to show the initializing message for a long time. I found [this other thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57456) about the same issue. 
I believe this prevented me from proceeding and connecting a monitor helped me.

But when I disconnected the ethernet cable from the router this message disappeared. So I could choose 'wheezy' and install it.

After connecting the ethernet cable back to the PC I just shared my 'wifi' connection by choosing 'Ethernet' as the option(See the question).

I didn't bridge it (See the comments).

This command showed the Pi's IP and I connected to it using Putty.

```
     arp -a | findstr b8-27-eb
```